# PostgreSQL формат даты DD.MM.YYYY

Tags: sql, postgresql

Как создать таблицу с форматом даты DD.MM.YYYY или как вывести с помощью SELECT запроса формат даты DD.MM.YYYY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select to_char(some_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy') from some_table;
```

Соответствующий [раздел документации](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html).

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что *some_date* в вашем коде это название столбца? А то у меня вот такой ответ выводит `[RealDictRow([('to_char', '25.09.2002')])]`, а должен быть `[RealDictRow([('some_date', '25.09.2002')])]`

Comment: Да, правильно. Чтобы название столбца не подменялось название фунции, можно добавить алиас к вызову - `to_char(some_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy') as some_date`